# My normal guiscale is the same as large & auto

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My normal guiscale is the same as large & auto except for small. When I go on fullscreen i can change my gui scale but when I play on windowed I can't change it. I know it's not a big deal but the crosshair & other mods take up my whole screen, and small is too small for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen resolution (or window size) probably just isn't high(/big) enough. These sizes are just the maximum, they still scale down if they can't fit into the window.